# Big-O notation explanation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, asymptotics

[image]

I still can't get it while not seeing examples on how to calculate the O-notations.

Can anyone explain step by step at least one of the examples, please?
As I understand, I need to find $C$ and $k$?

Prove that:
$$f(x) =\frac{(x^4+x^2+1)}{x^3} \;\;\mbox{ is }\;\; O(x).$$
$$f(x) =(1+\frac{1}{x^2})·(1+\frac{5}{x^3}) \;\;\mbox{ is }\;\; O(1).$$
$$f(x) = \frac{\log(2x)}{\log(x)} \;\;\mbox{ is }\;\; O(1).$$

Comment: Is $$\frac{x^4 + x^2 + 1/x^3}{x}$$ bounded above and below (for sufficiently large $x$)?    Same question for $$\frac{(1+(1/x^2))\cdot(1+(5/x^3))}{1}$$ and for $$\frac{\log(2x)/\log(x)}{1}$$?

Comment: @EricTowers Hi. (x4+x2+1)/x3  ,  (1+(1/x2))⋅(1+(5/x3)), log(2x)/log(x)

Comment: First instance is lacking parens, but I blame the formatting of the Question for being difficult to read.

Comment: But I notice you have said nothing about boundedness.  Can you try to find the maximum and minimum of the (with one correction) expressions I provided?

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry. I don't know how to re-write it otherwise:/

Comment: For instance: Find the maximum and minimum values of $$ \frac{(x^4 + x^2+1)/x^3}{x}$$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: What textbook/workbook is this example coming from?  Because, the typical definition should give $F(n)=7n^2$ as $O(n^2)$.  Does your example have a typo, or is the textbook author using a non-standard definition?

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter Discrete mathematics and its applications (2019, McGraw-Hill) Rosen, Kenneth H

Comment: Unfortunately, that "Example2" seems to be a bit sloppy with terminology when compared to the good "Example1" of $F(x)=2x^2 +2x+1$ is $O(x^2)$ on an earlier page.  When the author says "Show that $7x^2$ is $O(x^3)$." they seem to mean "Show that $7x^2$ is dominated by $O(x^3)$." which is what they show in their solution (and would also be true for $O(x^4)$, $O(x^5)$ and higher orders of $x$).  It is sloppy because $7x^2$ is $O(x^2)$ would also be correct by the usual definition and following from "Example1".  I'll try to write up an answer this afternoon when I'm not on my lunch break.

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter ... Yes, $2x^2+2x+1$ is $O(x^3)$.  Check the standard definitions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Efremova: Do you know enough calculus to compute limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a quick look, the textbook is gearing up to properly define $\Theta(\dots)$ , which is the "Big Oh" folks typically try to *mean* when talking about *'the'* order a function belongs to, and the book is *properly* defining $O(\dots)$ and $\Omega(\dots)$ on the way toward that goal.

So, I was wrong in my comments about "Show that $7x^2$ is $O(x^3)$." being sloppy; the book is trying to very deliberately show that $O(\dots)$ is not a 1-to-1 assignment* and that it really is perfectly valid that "$7x^2$ is $O(x^2)$" and "$7x^2$ is $O(x^3)$" and "$7x^2$ is $O(x^{100})$" can be all concurrently true.

* My treating $O(\dots)$ as if it were 1-to-1 (by thinking $7x^2 \to O(x^2)$ and *only* so) was the true sloppiness!

---

So, how does this $O(\dots)$ thing work?

Basically we're comparing two different functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and trying to figure out if $|f(x)|$ ever grows slower than $|g(x)|$ for "large x". (With some extra wiggle room allowing $g(x)$ to scale by a constant.)

This is very easy if we're comparing apples-to-apples examples like $f(x)=x^2$ versus $g(x)=x^3$, but becomes more difficult if we're comparing apples-to-oranges examples like $7x^2$ versus $2x^3$, and even more difficult still for apples-to-bananas examples like $(7x^2-4)$ versus $(2x^3-17x^2+51)$.

Really, though, we just have to get far enough away from the "small x" values where the two curves might still be criss-crossing and get out to "large x" where we can say definitively which curve wins.  That's what the whole "witness" thing is about.  We just need to provide one witness pair $\{x_w,C_w\}$ to show that $|f(x>x_w)|<C_w\cdot |g(x>x_w)|$ *can* happen in order to prove that $g(x)$ *can* beat $f(x)$.

Let's draw an example:
[image: Three different witnesses]

In the above picture, the blue $f(x)$ looks like it will always be larger than $g(x)$ no matter how big of an $x$ we choose... so no pink witness pair $\{x_{w,pink},C_{w,pink}=1\}$ will work.  However, from where the red witness is standing it looks like $2g(x)>f(x)$ will always be true (to his right), and similarly for the crimson witness who sees $4g(x)>f(x)$ even from his position at an even smaller $x_w$.

From the above we can see that we can either A) pick a constant $C_w$ and find a witness $x_w$ where "everything to the right" wins, or B) pick a witness $x_w$ and then choose a big enough $C_w$ that "everything to the right" wins.

---

So, on to some examples:

> $f(x)=\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^3}$ versus $g(x)=x$

If we expand and simplify $f(x)$ we get:

$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3}$

This looks *very* similar to $g(x)=x$, but unfortunately $\frac{1}{x}>0$ and $\frac{1}{x^3}>0$ (for all $x>0$) so $|f(x)|>1\cdot|g(x)|$.  However, $\frac{1}{x}>0$ and $\frac{1}{x^3}>0$ are both pretty small for $x>0$ so we can probably just choose a "bigger" constant $C_w$ and find some $x_w$ that'll make it work.

Lets try $C_w=2$.  In that case, we're looking at whether $|x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3}|<2|x|$ for some choice of $x_w$.  This seems like it can totally work! We just need to find some $x_w$ such that $|x+(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3})|<2|x|$ is always true for $x>x_w$. Does $x_w=1$ work for the $C_w=2$ we chose? Nope, in that case we'd have $|1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1^3}|<2|1|$ but $3<2$ is totally false.  How about $x_w=2$? In that case, $|2+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3})|<2|2|$ gives $2.625<4.0$ which totally checks out.  So, we found a witness pair $\{x_w=2,C_w=2\}$ ($\{k,C\}$ in your book's notation) that proves $f(x)$ is $O(x^2)$ is possible.

> $f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x^2})·(1+\frac{5}{x^3})$ versus $g(x)=1$

If we expand and simplify $f(x)$ we get:

$f(x)=1 + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{5}{x^3} + \frac{5}{x^5}$

This feels very similar to the previous example, except now we're looking to choose a $C_w$ value such that $|1+(\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{5}{x^3} + \frac{5}{x^5})|<C_w|1|$ for some $x_w$ value.  There are a couple different ways to go.  You could choose a $C_w$ and then solve for $x_w$ until it works (like we did last time).  But also, we could try setting $x_w=1$ and then just making $C_w$ so big it has to work (in other words $C_w>12$).

> $f(x)=\frac{ln(2x)}{ln(x)}$ versus $g(x)=1$

If we use some logarithmic identities to expand and simplify $f(x)$ we get:

$f(x)=\frac{ln(2)+ln(x)}{ln(x)}=1+\frac{ln(2)}{ln(x)}$

and once again it shouldn't be too difficult to find some $x_w$-and-$C_w$ pair such that $|1+\frac{ln(2)}{ln(x)}|<C_w|1|$ is always true.

---

Next up the book will have you follow some very similar exercises (just flipping the inequality to $|f(x)|>C_w|g(x)|$) to prove $\Omega(\dots)$.

Then, you'll see if you can sandwich a function between both $O(\dots)$ and $\Omega(\dots)$ to get the $\Theta(\dots)$ order.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I was confused with a O(1) as it says it some constant, but then I got stuck really. Best explanation ever.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim**
$$\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^3} = O(x)\qquad\text{as } x \to +\infty .\tag1$$
**Proof**
For $x > 1$ we have
$$
\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^3} =
x + \frac{x}{x^2} + \frac{x}{x^4} < x + x + x = 3x
$$
So $k=1, C=3$ witnesses $(1)$.

Comment: And how does the O(1) work? Thanks for the answer.:)

Comment: I think it is time for Efremova to do the second one.